What could have caused this SSD to be no longer recoverable?
So a friend called me in January as his PC couldn't boot into Win10 and ended up in BIOS every time on startup. Since no boot device was found, I removed the SSD from the tower and connected it to my laptop (Ubuntu 23.04) with an USB-caddy. The SSD got mounted as /dev/sda but wasn't visible in the file manager.
I then:

checked with "Disks" which showed the drive as "OK" but "Unknown": (this screenshot is from now, but I'm pretty sure it was the same back then)
tried to mount it with mount /dev/sda /mnt - no success
did a SMART check, the result of which I can't remember exactly, but it wasn't really helpful
fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: PSSD T7         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 18DA2570-EC92-4A71-A1B7-346EF89B0795


tried ntfsfix /dev/sda - no success
tried ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sda /media/user/Samsung T7/copy2.img /media/user/Samsung T7/status2.log twice - first time ended up with an img of 29.7 MB which I tried to recover with photorec, but no success:

# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.27
# Command line: ddrescue -d /dev/sda /media/user/Samsung T7/copy.img /media/user/Samsung T7/status.log
# Start time:   2024-01-09 22:31:12
# Current time: 2024-01-09 22:31:12
# current_pos  current_status  current_pass
0x00000000     ?               1
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x1BF2976000  ?

second time I kept it running for 16 hours, then interrupted - returned an empty img file - see logs:
# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.27
# Command line: ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sda /media/nicu/Samsung T7/copy2.img /media/nicu/Samsung T7/status2.log
# Start time:   2024-01-09 22:38:33
# Current time: 2024-01-10 14:36:39
# Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 5 (forwards)
# current_pos  current_status  current_pass
0x00690000     ?               5
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x00690000  *
0x00690000  0x001E0000  ?
0x00870000  0x00020000  *
0x00890000  0x00970000  ?
0x01200000  0x00020000  *
0x01220000  0x012F0000  ?
0x02510000  0x00020000  *
0x02530000  0x025F0000  ?
0x04B20000  0x00020000  *
0x04B40000  0x04BF0000  ?
0x09730000  0x00020000  *
0x09750000  0x097F0000  ?
0x12F40000  0x00020000  *
0x12F60000  0x12FF0000  ?
0x25F50000  0x00020000  *
0x25F70000  0x25FF0000  ?
0x4BF60000  0x00020000  *
0x4BF80000  0x478B0000  ?
0x93830000  0x00010000  *
0x93840000  0x478B0000  ?
0xDB0F0000  0x00010000  *
0xDB100000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1229B0000  0x00010000  *
0x1229C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x16A270000  0x00010000  *
0x16A280000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1B1B30000  0x00010000  *
0x1B1B40000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1F93F0000  0x00010000  *
0x1F9400000  0x478B0000  ?
0x240CB0000  0x00010000  *
0x240CC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x288570000  0x00010000  *
0x288580000  0x478B0000  ?
0x2CFE30000  0x00010000  *
0x2CFE40000  0x478B0000  ?
0x3176F0000  0x00010000  *
0x317700000  0x478B0000  ?
0x35EFB0000  0x00010000  *
0x35EFC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x3A6870000  0x00010000  *
0x3A6880000  0x478B0000  ?
0x3EE130000  0x00010000  *
0x3EE140000  0x478B0000  ?
0x4359F0000  0x00010000  *
0x435A00000  0x478B0000  ?
0x47D2B0000  0x00010000  *
0x47D2C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x4C4B70000  0x00010000  *
0x4C4B80000  0x478B0000  ?
0x50C430000  0x00010000  *
0x50C440000  0x478B0000  ?
0x553CF0000  0x00010000  *
0x553D00000  0x478B0000  ?
0x59B5B0000  0x00010000  *
0x59B5C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x5E2E70000  0x00010000  *
0x5E2E80000  0x478B0000  ?
0x62A730000  0x00010000  *
0x62A740000  0x478B0000  ?
0x671FF0000  0x00010000  *
0x672000000  0x478B0000  ?
0x6B98B0000  0x00010000  *
0x6B98C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x701170000  0x00010000  *
0x701180000  0x478B0000  ?
0x748A30000  0x00010000  *
0x748A40000  0x478B0000  ?
0x7902F0000  0x00010000  *
0x790300000  0x478B0000  ?
0x7D7BB0000  0x00010000  *
0x7D7BC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x81F470000  0x00010000  *
0x81F480000  0x478B0000  ?
0x866D30000  0x00010000  *
0x866D40000  0x478B0000  ?
0x8AE5F0000  0x00010000  *
0x8AE600000  0x478B0000  ?
0x8F5EB0000  0x00010000  *
0x8F5EC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x93D770000  0x00010000  *
0x93D780000  0x478B0000  ?
0x985030000  0x00010000  *
0x985040000  0x478B0000  ?
0x9CC8F0000  0x00010000  *
0x9CC900000  0x478B0000  ?
0xA141B0000  0x00010000  *
0xA141C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xA5BA70000  0x00010000  *
0xA5BA80000  0x478B0000  ?
0xAA3330000  0x00010000  *
0xAA3340000  0x478B0000  ?
0xAEABF0000  0x00010000  *
0xAEAC00000  0x478B0000  ?
0xB324B0000  0x00010000  *
0xB324C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xB79D70000  0x00010000  *
0xB79D80000  0x478B0000  ?
0xBC1630000  0x00010000  *
0xBC1640000  0x478B0000  ?
0xC08EF0000  0x00010000  *
0xC08F00000  0x478B0000  ?
0xC507B0000  0x00010000  *
0xC507C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xC98070000  0x00010000  *
0xC98080000  0x478B0000  ?
0xCDF930000  0x00010000  *
0xCDF940000  0x478B0000  ?
0xD271F0000  0x00010000  *
0xD27200000  0x478B0000  ?
0xD6EAB0000  0x00010000  *
0xD6EAC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xDB6370000  0x00010000  *
0xDB6380000  0x478B0000  ?
0xDFDC30000  0x00010000  *
0xDFDC40000  0x478B0000  ?
0xE454F0000  0x00010000  *
0xE45500000  0x478B0000  ?
0xE8CDB0000  0x00010000  *
0xE8CDC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xED4670000  0x00010000  *
0xED4680000  0x478B0000  ?
0xF1BF30000  0x00010000  *
0xF1BF40000  0x478B0000  ?
0xF637F0000  0x00010000  *
0xF63800000  0x478B0000  ?
0xFAB0B0000  0x00010000  *
0xFAB0C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xFF2970000  0x00010000  *
0xFF2980000  0x478B0000  ?
0x103A230000  0x00010000  *
0x103A240000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1081AF0000  0x00010000  *
0x1081B00000  0x478B0000  ?
0x10C93B0000  0x00010000  *
0x10C93C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1110C70000  0x00010000  *
0x1110C80000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1158530000  0x00010000  *
0x1158540000  0x478B0000  ?
0x119FDF0000  0x00010000  *
0x119FE00000  0x478B0000  ?
0x11E76B0000  0x00010000  *
0x11E76C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x122EF70000  0x00010000  *
0x122EF80000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1276830000  0x00010000  *
0x1276840000  0x478B0000  ?
0x12BE0F0000  0x00010000  *
0x12BE100000  0x478B0000  ?
0x13059B0000  0x00010000  *
0x13059C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x134D270000  0x00010000  *
0x134D280000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1394B30000  0x00010000  *
0x1394B40000  0x478B0000  ?
0x13DC3F0000  0x00010000  *
0x13DC400000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1423CB0000  0x00010000  *
0x1423CC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x146B570000  0x00010000  *
0x146B580000  0x478B0000  ?
0x14B2E30000  0x00010000  *
0x14B2E40000  0x478B0000  ?
0x14FA6F0000  0x00010000  *
0x14FA700000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1541FB0000  0x00010000  *
0x1541FC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1589870000  0x00010000  *
0x1589880000  0x478B0000  ?
0x15D1130000  0x00010000  *
0x15D1140000  0x478B0000  ?
0x16189F0000  0x00010000  *
0x1618A00000  0x478B0000  ?
0x16602B0000  0x00010000  *
0x16602C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x16A7B70000  0x00010000  *
0x16A7B80000  0x478B0000  ?
0x16EF430000  0x00010000  *
0x16EF440000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1736CF0000  0x00010000  *
0x1736D00000  0x478B0000  ?
0x177E5B0000  0x00010000  *
0x177E5C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x17C5E70000  0x00010000  *
0x17C5E80000  0x478B0000  ?
0x180D730000  0x00010000  *
0x180D740000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1854FF0000  0x00010000  *
0x1855000000  0x478B0000  ?
0x189C8B0000  0x00010000  *
0x189C8C0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x18E4170000  0x00010000  *
0x18E4180000  0x478B0000  ?
0x192BA30000  0x00010000  *
0x192BA40000  0x478B0000  ?
0x19732F0000  0x00010000  *
0x1973300000  0x478B0000  ?
0x19BABB0000  0x00010000  *
0x19BABC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1A02470000  0x00010000  *
0x1A02480000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1A49D30000  0x00010000  *
0x1A49D40000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1A915F0000  0x00010000  *
0x1A91600000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1AD8EB0000  0x00010000  *
0x1AD8EC0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1B20770000  0x00010000  *
0x1B20780000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1B68030000  0x00010000  *
0x1B68040000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1BAF8F0000  0x00010000  *
0x1BAF900000  0x43070000  ?
0x1BF2970000  0x00006000  *


switched to an old Win10 laptop and tried to scan the drive with “AOMEI Partition Assistant Demo Edition”, but it didn't work because an error occurred or the drive wasn't even recognized (I can't remember exactly)
also on the Win10 laptop tried to scan the drive with R-Linux, which failed because of a read error on a sector:
switched back to Ubuntu laptop and also tried there with R-Linux - no succuess
sent the SSD to “KLDiscovery Ontrack” where it was analyzed in a lab (at least that's what they told us). They then wrote to us that 100% of the sectors could be read but were either filled with zeros or some kind of pattern, making it impossible to recover data. (After some time I got unsure if we can trust them and kept trying.)
tried with dd if=/dev/sda of=dump.dd conv=noerror,sync (for details see: Can't dd broken SSD) with disabled UAS, since the dmesg logs implied some issue related to that.
tried again with ddrescue, also with UAS disabled and with another caddy (RSHTECH instead of ugreen). This also returned an img with 29.7 MB, on which photorec also couldn't recover something:

user@ubuntu:~$ sudo ddrescue -d /dev/sda /home/user/Downloads/copy.img /home/user/Downloads/status.log
GNU ddrescue 1.27
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:  118939 MB, non-trimmed:    2276 kB,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:  118939 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:    1506 B/s
non-tried:  120002 MB,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:      87 B/s
  rescued:   29687 kB,   bad areas:        0,        run time:  5h 28m 28s
pct rescued:    0.02%, read errors:      109,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read:  5h 25m 22s
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 1 (forwards)
     ipos:   68550 kB, non-trimmed:    7495 kB,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:   68550 kB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:     770 B/s
non-tried:  119996 MB,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:     364 B/s
  rescued:   29687 kB,   bad areas:        0,        run time: 10h 41m 47s
pct rescued:    0.02%, read errors:      213,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read: 10h 38m 41s
Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 2 (backwards)

logs:
# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.27
# Command line: ddrescue /dev/sda /home/user/Downloads/copy.img /home/user/Downloads/status.log
# Start time:   2024-11-18 10:48:16
# Current time: 2024-11-18 17:43:51
# Copying non-tried blocks... Pass 5 (forwards)
# current_pos  current_status  current_pass
0x02590000     ?               5
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x01C50000  +
0x01C50000  0x00940000  *
0x02590000  0x008C0000  ?
0x02E50000  0x00020000  *
0x02E70000  0x012F0000  ?
0x04160000  0x00020000  *
0x04180000  0x025F0000  ?
0x06770000  0x00020000  *
0x06790000  0x04BF0000  ?
0x0B380000  0x00020000  *
0x0B3A0000  0x097F0000  ?
0x14B90000  0x00020000  *
0x14BB0000  0x12FF0000  ?
0x27BA0000  0x00020000  *
0x27BC0000  0x25FF0000  ?
0x4DBB0000  0x00020000  *
0x4DBD0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x95480000  0x00010000  *
0x95490000  0x478B0000  ?
0xDCD40000  0x00010000  *
0xDCD50000  0x478B0000  ?
0x124600000  0x00010000  *
0x124610000  0x478B0000  ?
0x16BEC0000  0x00010000  *
0x16BED0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1B3780000  0x00010000  *
0x1B3790000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1FB040000  0x00010000  *
0x1FB050000  0x478B0000  ?
0x242900000  0x00010000  *
0x242910000  0x478B0000  ?
0x28A1C0000  0x00010000  *
0x28A1D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x2D1A80000  0x00010000  *
0x2D1A90000  0x478B0000  ?
0x319340000  0x00010000  *
0x319350000  0x478B0000  ?
0x360C00000  0x00010000  *
0x360C10000  0x478B0000  ?
0x3A84C0000  0x00010000  *
0x3A84D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x3EFD80000  0x00010000  *
0x3EFD90000  0x478B0000  ?
0x437640000  0x00010000  *
0x437650000  0x478B0000  ?
0x47EF00000  0x00010000  *
0x47EF10000  0x478B0000  ?
0x4C67C0000  0x00010000  *
0x4C67D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x50E080000  0x00010000  *
0x50E090000  0x478B0000  ?
0x555940000  0x00010000  *
0x555950000  0x478B0000  ?
0x59D200000  0x00010000  *
0x59D210000  0x478B0000  ?
0x5E4AC0000  0x00010000  *
0x5E4AD0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x62C380000  0x00010000  *
0x62C390000  0x478B0000  ?
0x673C40000  0x00010000  *
0x673C50000  0x478B0000  ?
0x6BB500000  0x00010000  *
0x6BB510000  0x478B0000  ?
0x702DC0000  0x00010000  *
0x702DD0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x74A680000  0x00010000  *
0x74A690000  0x478B0000  ?
0x791F40000  0x00010000  *
0x791F50000  0x478B0000  ?
0x7D9800000  0x00010000  *
0x7D9810000  0x478B0000  ?
0x8210C0000  0x00010000  *
0x8210D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x868980000  0x00010000  *
0x868990000  0x478B0000  ?
0x8B0240000  0x00010000  *
0x8B0250000  0x478B0000  ?
0x8F7B00000  0x00010000  *
0x8F7B10000  0x478B0000  ?
0x93F3C0000  0x00010000  *
0x93F3D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x986C80000  0x00010000  *
0x986C90000  0x478B0000  ?
0x9CE540000  0x00010000  *
0x9CE550000  0x478B0000  ?
0xA15E00000  0x00010000  *
0xA15E10000  0x478B0000  ?
0xA5D6C0000  0x00010000  *
0xA5D6D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xAA4F80000  0x00010000  *
0xAA4F90000  0x478B0000  ?
0xAEC840000  0x00010000  *
0xAEC850000  0x478B0000  ?
0xB34100000  0x00010000  *
0xB34110000  0x478B0000  ?
0xB7B9C0000  0x00010000  *
0xB7B9D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xBC3280000  0x00010000  *
0xBC3290000  0x478B0000  ?
0xC0AB40000  0x00010000  *
0xC0AB50000  0x478B0000  ?
0xC52400000  0x00010000  *
0xC52410000  0x478B0000  ?
0xC99CC0000  0x00010000  *
0xC99CD0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xCE1580000  0x00010000  *
0xCE1590000  0x478B0000  ?
0xD28E40000  0x00010000  *
0xD28E50000  0x478B0000  ?
0xD70700000  0x00010000  *
0xD70710000  0x478B0000  ?
0xDB7FC0000  0x00010000  *
0xDB7FD0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xDFF880000  0x00010000  *
0xDFF890000  0x478B0000  ?
0xE47140000  0x00010000  *
0xE47150000  0x478B0000  ?
0xE8EA00000  0x00010000  *
0xE8EA10000  0x478B0000  ?
0xED62C0000  0x00010000  *
0xED62D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0xF1DB80000  0x00010000  *
0xF1DB90000  0x478B0000  ?
0xF65440000  0x00010000  *
0xF65450000  0x478B0000  ?
0xFACD00000  0x00010000  *
0xFACD10000  0x478B0000  ?
0xFF45C0000  0x00010000  *
0xFF45D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x103BE80000  0x00010000  *
0x103BE90000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1083740000  0x00010000  *
0x1083750000  0x478B0000  ?
0x10CB000000  0x00010000  *
0x10CB010000  0x478B0000  ?
0x11128C0000  0x00010000  *
0x11128D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x115A180000  0x00010000  *
0x115A190000  0x478B0000  ?
0x11A1A40000  0x00010000  *
0x11A1A50000  0x478B0000  ?
0x11E9300000  0x00010000  *
0x11E9310000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1230BC0000  0x00010000  *
0x1230BD0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1278480000  0x00010000  *
0x1278490000  0x478B0000  ?
0x12BFD40000  0x00010000  *
0x12BFD50000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1307600000  0x00010000  *
0x1307610000  0x478B0000  ?
0x134EEC0000  0x00010000  *
0x134EED0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1396780000  0x00010000  *
0x1396790000  0x478B0000  ?
0x13DE040000  0x00010000  *
0x13DE050000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1425900000  0x00010000  *
0x1425910000  0x478B0000  ?
0x146D1C0000  0x00010000  *
0x146D1D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x14B4A80000  0x00010000  *
0x14B4A90000  0x478B0000  ?
0x14FC340000  0x00010000  *
0x14FC350000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1543C00000  0x00010000  *
0x1543C10000  0x478B0000  ?
0x158B4C0000  0x00010000  *
0x158B4D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x15D2D80000  0x00010000  *
0x15D2D90000  0x478B0000  ?
0x161A640000  0x00010000  *
0x161A650000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1661F00000  0x00010000  *
0x1661F10000  0x478B0000  ?
0x16A97C0000  0x00010000  *
0x16A97D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x16F1080000  0x00010000  *
0x16F1090000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1738940000  0x00010000  *
0x1738950000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1780200000  0x00010000  *
0x1780210000  0x478B0000  ?
0x17C7AC0000  0x00010000  *
0x17C7AD0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x180F380000  0x00010000  *
0x180F390000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1856C40000  0x00010000  *
0x1856C50000  0x478B0000  ?
0x189E500000  0x00010000  *
0x189E510000  0x478B0000  ?
0x18E5DC0000  0x00010000  *
0x18E5DD0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x192D680000  0x00010000  *
0x192D690000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1974F40000  0x00010000  *
0x1974F50000  0x478B0000  ?
0x19BC800000  0x00010000  *
0x19BC810000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1A040C0000  0x00010000  *
0x1A040D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1A4B980000  0x00010000  *
0x1A4B990000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1A93240000  0x00010000  *
0x1A93250000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1ADAB00000  0x00010000  *
0x1ADAB10000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1B223C0000  0x00010000  *
0x1B223D0000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1B69C80000  0x00010000  *
0x1B69C90000  0x478B0000  ?
0x1BB1540000  0x00010000  *
0x1BB1550000  0x41420000  ?
0x1BF2970000  0x00006000  *

dmesg:
[Sa Nov 16 22:35:01 2024] I/O error, dev sda, sector 11924992 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 13 prio class 2
[Sa Nov 16 22:38:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:38:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:38:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[Sa Nov 16 22:38:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[Sa Nov 16 22:38:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 92 30 00 00 00 61 00
[Sa Nov 16 22:38:02 2024] I/O error, dev sda, sector 9580544 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 13 prio class 2
[Sa Nov 16 22:41:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:41:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:41:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[Sa Nov 16 22:41:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[Sa Nov 16 22:41:02 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 6e 6a 00 00 00 61 00
[Sa Nov 16 22:41:02 2024] I/O error, dev sda, sector 7236096 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 13 prio class 2
[Sa Nov 16 22:44:03 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:44:03 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:44:03 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[Sa Nov 16 22:44:03 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[Sa Nov 16 22:44:03 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 4a a4 00 00 00 61 00
[Sa Nov 16 22:44:03 2024] I/O error, dev sda, sector 4891648 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 13 prio class 2
[Sa Nov 16 22:47:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:47:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:47:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[Sa Nov 16 22:47:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[Sa Nov 16 22:47:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 26 dd 80 00 00 80 00
[Sa Nov 16 22:47:04 2024] I/O error, dev sda, sector 2547072 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
[Sa Nov 16 22:50:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:50:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:50:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[Sa Nov 16 22:50:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[Sa Nov 16 22:50:04 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 13 dd 00 00 00 80 00
[Sa Nov 16 22:50:04 2024] I/O error, dev sda, sector 1301760 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
[Sa Nov 16 22:53:05 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:53:05 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:53:05 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[Sa Nov 16 22:53:05 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[Sa Nov 16 22:53:05 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 0a 5c 80 00 00 80 00
[Sa Nov 16 22:53:05 2024] I/O error, dev sda, sector 679040 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
[Sa Nov 16 22:56:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:56:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:56:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[Sa Nov 16 22:56:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[Sa Nov 16 22:56:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 05 9c 00 00 00 80 00
[Sa Nov 16 22:56:06 2024] I/O error, dev sda, sector 367616 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 2
[Sa Nov 16 22:59:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:59:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
[Sa Nov 16 22:59:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[Sa Nov 16 22:59:06 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready


tried photorec directly on the SSD:


So now I'm giving up (unless someone has another idea). My question now: is it possible that the data on an SSD can suddenly be zeroed or filled with a pattern (like Ontrack said)? Was it me who caused the issue because of the things/tools I tried or is it possible that this happened already before? Of course I know it's hard to say, but I want to at least try to understand what might have been going on. The SSD (Kingston SA400S37/120G, SBFK71E0) has been used for more than 10 years and my friend had installed a new router before the boot problem occurred and therefore had to plug/unplug some devices to the same socket that the PC was connected to. Is it possible that some voltage peak could have caused the issue?
Thanks for any help!
Edit:
Thanks to @telcoM !
The controller most likely blocks the access due to an internal error on the SSD and that's why it's identified as SATAFIRM S11. This seems to be a known thing for those Kingston Models.
The only chance to recover some data seems to be with a "PC-3000".
For more details see:
https://www.elektroda.com/rtvforum/topic3859967.html
https://youtu.be/xvBJzIo_PTk
The only odd thing remaining is that Ontrack ignored or didn't realize that it's a controller issue and not zeroed data.

Have seen this multiple times, I'm afraid it is not salvagable by any non-professional means, and it would cost a mayhem of $$ if some lab was able to recover it. Sorry

You run format repairs on formatted partitions not drives, unless in very unusual case where drive was formatted. You show gpt partitioning, does this show any partitions as gpt also has backup partition table at end of drive for emergency? sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda Or does testdisk show anything? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

The fact that the device identifies as SATAFIRM S11 is significant: it indicates the flash drive controller's firmware has crashed or has been lost, and the controller is in firmware recovery mode. Googling with that string brings results indicating it might be possible to reinstall the firmware to make the SSD work again, but the firmware recovery is likely to cause a loss of all existing data.

It seems that some data recovery professionals advertise the capability to recover data using some special tools, but if you've already had that drive analyzed by Ontrack (I think they used to be one of the best in HDD data recovery, I'd expect them to have good capabilities with SSDs too by now), I would not hold much hope.

It looks like there might be a hardware defect if you've tried using the SSD on different devices with different operating systems and during your tests.
Here's a list of additional tools, though I doubt they will not help based on the details in your question.
PC was hanging, "Physical Volumes: not OK (BAD)"
Cloning data from a damaged SSD
Comparison of disk cloning software
Disk cloning ArchWiki
The issue could be caused by power fluctuations, software, or simply hardware failure due to aging.
Even if you format the drive, without backing up the data, even if it works and you test it, you should avoid using this SSD in the future anymore.
If there are critical files on it, a professional data recovery company or specialist with the necessary tools and hardware would be required.
However, this can be very expensive.
Consider your options carefully and always have backups in the future.
